# Vaadin combobox Custom Item Template does not work

Tags: combobox, polymer, vaadin

Hello Stackoverflow users, I am trying to use a vaading combobox in a polymer app with a Custom Item Template as shown in  [the official docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/elements/vaadin-combo-box/vaadin-combo-box-item-template.html).

I tried the example code of the docs:

```html
<vaadin-combo-box
    id="elements-template-box"
    label="Element"
    item-label-path="name"
    item-value-path="symbol">
  <template>
    <b>[[item.name]], <sub>[[item.number]]</sub>[[item.symbol]]</b><br>
    array index: [[index]]
  </template>
</vaadin-combo-box>

<script>
  var elementsTemplateBox = document.querySelector('#elements-template-box');

  // elementsJson is an Array of Objects. Item object format:
  //   {name: 'Hydrogen', symbol: 'H', number: 1}
  elementsTemplateBox.items = elementsJson;
</script>
```

But it does not work : there is only the list of the name property but not the other properties. It is as if the template included inside the vaadin-combo-box has no effect.

Could you help me ?

Thanks

Phil

Comment: Hi! This feature is not yet released, it’s only available in the master branch (soon released as 1.3 beta). If you want to try it now, you can install the element with "bower install vaadin-combo-box#master"

Comment: Thank you,  I will test.